# How to make every 'beginner' shown at random during the run of the program

Tags: python, math, random

Im currently in make of creating a math game that involves: addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. These parts with purple borders around them are the questions that i had created for the addition part when the user chooses to pick addition.

I dont know how to make these question be shown at random. When the user goes to select addition for addition questions everytime he does or goes back to do it again after he is done i want the questions not to be the same each time i want them to be in a different order. So its random each time.

```html
#addition questions
def beginnerquestionsaddition():
    os.system('clear')
    score = 0
    beginner1 = input("2 + 3 = ")
    if beginner1 == ("5"):
        print("Correct, Well Done!")
        score += 1
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("Sorry you got it wrong :(")
        time.sleep(1)
    os.system('clear')

    beginner2 = input("6 + 7 = ")
    if beginner2 == ("13"):
        print("Correct, Well Done!")
        score += 1
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("Sorry you got it wrong :(")
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('clear')
    
    beginner3 = input("2 + 5 = ")
    if beginner3 == ("7"):
        print("Correct, Well Done!")
        score += 1
        os.system('clear')
        time.sleep(1)
        endquestadditionbeginner()
        print("your score was: ")
        print(score)
        time.sleep(3)
        introduction()
    else:
        print("Sorry you got it wrong :(")
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('clear')
        endquestadditionbeginner()
        print("your score was: ")
        print(score)
        time.sleep(3)
        introduction()
```

Comment: Please post code as plain text, not an image.

Comment: Put all the questions and answers in a list. Pick a random list element, show the question, and check the response against the corresponding answer.

Comment: There are many question already on SO, and many sites on line, that demonstrate how to display random Q&A sequences.  We expect you to research these before posting here.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: thanks for letting me know wont make that mistake again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this isn't exactly an answer for the specific way you decided to go about this program but this is a much simpler way:

```
from random import randrange

def beginner_addition():
    A = randrange(1,11)  # Increase range on harder questions
    B = randrange(1,11)  # Ex. for intermediate_addition(), randrange would be (10,21) maybe...
    C = A + B
    ans = input("What's the answer to " + str(A) + "+" + str(B) + "? ")
    if ans == str(C):
        print('Correct')
    else:
        print('Incorrect')

while True:
    beginner_addition()
```

Of course, this is just example code. You could easily include your points system and perhaps move up in difficulty when the points hit a certain level. You could also randomize the operation. Sorry if this isn't what you want but I saw your code and I figured there is nothing wrong with simplifying your code...

Comment: Thanks for that. Il apply it in and il see how i go

Comment: @nath2125 No problem, It should cut your code by like 80% at least. Also make sure you put all your stuff for correct and incorrect answers into functions as well. Don't put your whole program into functions though.

Comment: Yea will do for sure.